# Display image along with other data in a table

Tags: php, mysql, image

I know it's not the greatest technique, but coming from Foxpro and Dbase background, some habits just don't die. I am absolutely fresh in PHP and trying to re-create learning curve of my earlier programming experience.

I have drilled GOOGLE for the issue and tried to come up with the script, only issue is sometimes I came up with garbles, sometime empty screen, sometimes only IMAGE.
The scenario is If I am able to create this simple script, I will probably understand how to handle images issue.

I have a database in my `MYSQL` called `crm`. In the database I have a table called `mast_cust` with fields `f_name`, `l_name` and `pic` (BLOB)

I already have some records in them.

What I understood was:

- Images and Data (Textual) cannot be printed together
- You have to have  two scripts , one gathering the image and the other gathering data
- The one which gathers data , calls the one which collects images and prints it.

What I want is, to see data in tabular format

```
First Name |   Last Name    |    Image
```

These are my two scripts, which is the one which prints garble
Script 1 : Main PHP file - `list.php`
Script 2 : Image Storing Script: `pix.php`

---

list.php

```
<?php
  $errmsg = "";

  if (! @mysql_connect("localhost","root","Admin"))
  {
    $errmsg = "Cannot connect to database";
  }
  @mysql_select_db("crm");

  $strSQL = "select f_name,l_name,pic from mast_cust";
  $rsPix = mysql_query($strSQL);
  $numRows = mysql_numrows($rsPix);
  $i = 0;

  while($i < $numRows){
?>
<img src="pix.php?pixID=<?php echo mysql_result($rsPix,$i,"pic"); ?>"/>
<?php
  $i++;
}
?>
```

---

Script 2 pix.php

```
<?php 
  $errmsg = "";
  if (! @mysql_connect("localhost","root","Admin"))
  {
    $errmsg = "Cannot connect to database";
  }
  @mysql_select_db("crm");

  if (IsSet($_GET['pixID'])){
    $gotten = @mysql_query("select pic from pix where cust_id = ".$_GET['pixID']);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($gotten))
    {
      print $row['pic'];

    }
    mysql_free_result($gotten);
  }
?>
```

---

Any help resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Whenever I see data used instead of actual locations they tend to have "data:" at the beginning of them. Perhaps add this to the beginning of your print statement: print "data:" + $row['pic']. That could be just for stylesheets however.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're storing the jpeg image as a blob in mysql.

1.) You can only send one pic at a time. So no need for a for loop.
2.) If so, you'll need to format the output of the data for the pic, so that a browser can read it.

I would recommend against this approach.  You should avoid using a relational database for storing images.  Try storing the jpegs on a regular filesystem or a file server (like S3), and store the url to it in the database.

If obfuscating the image url isn't enough, try the following approach:

[Echo/print a jpg-image with php, for safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422510/echo-print-a-jpg-image-with-php-for-safety)

It uses:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php