# How to Generate a Data URI

Tags: image-processing, data-uri, image-conversion

I recently came across Data URI scheme and was reading about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Example code looks something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
          AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
          9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

My question is this: How do you generate the code (IE: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...`) for using on a website?

*Note:* I am specifically looking for how this is done with no server side scripts. But you can still post server side script ways for others who may come across this question. Also I have seen websites that will do this for you, how can I do it myself?

Comment: You can look for base64 encoding feature in server side scripting language, or you can find some website that allows you to upload a file and returns you the base64 encoding of the image. There is also the meta data string (`data:image/png;base64,`) that you need to use some MIME detection function to get the MIME type.

Comment: @Lynda: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you have an image file that you want to convert to a data URI (fairly easy: follow link in the Wikipedia article to read about "base64")?  Maybe you have an array of raw pixels that you want to convert to a data URI (significantly harder).  Something else?

Comment: @Lynda: Also, when you say "I have seen websites that will do this for you, how can I do it myself?"  What part of using the website is it that you object to?  Are you looking to learn how to write a program to create data URIs?  Maybe instead you don't want to send your image over the network for the conversion, and so just want a standalone local program to do the conversion?

Comment: @Managu - I am more curious than anything but I have a few places where I might benefit. Also the issue with websites is the first few I went to were blocked warning of possible malware. A standalone program would not be bad, I am not looking to write a program.

Comment: I used this site. worked fine [enter link description here](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a cool way to do it for images when viewed in Google Chrome:

1. **Right-click** the image in question and choose **Inspect Element**
2. **Right-click** the image's URL (the cursor will turn into a hand) and choose **Open link in Resources Panel**
3. **Right-click** the image in the Resources Panel and choose **Copy image as Data URL**
4. **Paste** the Data URI wherever you need it

Comment: Nowaday the `Open link in Resources Panel` is named `Reveal in Sources Panel`

Answer (score 3):

If it's not clear from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), a Data URI is just a way of shoving the entire contents of a file (say, a png) into a text link.  Since many interesting types of files contain data that's not represented as text, the scheme uses the [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding to represent the full spectrum of possible binary data in a textual format.

In addition, when a browser retrieves a file from a web server, the web server tells the browser what type of file it is, in the form of a [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).  Since a data URI doesn't have a web server (or even a filename!) to identify the type of file, this information must be included in the URI.

Comment: This explains the Data URI concept well.

Answer (score 1):

(I can not comment yet, so I am adding this as a new answer.)

Similar to [Oran D. Lord's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942312/how-to-generate-a-data-uri/26147772#26147772), this should work in Firefox:

1. Open the image file in Firefox (or open a web page with the image).
2. Right-click the image and choose "Inspect Element".
3. In the Inspector, the image tag should now be highlighted. Right-click the image tag and and choose "Copy Image Data-URL" (even though it may not really be a URL, that is what the menu entry is currently called).
4. Paste the Data URI wherever you need it.