# is there any php solution for caching management ? especially for image caching?

Tags: php, caching

i just want to know a general information about this particular information. Any good reference will be helpful.

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cache+php

Comment: @gordon : cache for image or image who created on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image caching manual:

1. Store images in the disk directory.
2. Web-server will take care of caching.

Comment: without proper configuration, the webserver will cache nothing

Comment: With default configuration it will cache very well. and I am sorry, but your "proper configuration" note can be applied to any solution, thus, it has no sense.

Comment: in a foul mood today? you didn't even say which webserver, so I guess your entire answer is as senseless as my *proper configuration* then. but then again, I got the impression the answer wasn't meant to help the OP in the first place anyway.

Comment: I agree with this answer, actually.  The Question does not seem to be referring to opcode caching, rather, to caching generated images. What can you really do but just put them in a directory, check if it's there, and serve if so, generate if not? It wouldn't make sense to use memcached to store images, for instance, unless you have 18 zillion gb of ram.

Comment: Hey @Gordon. Please let me judge, what **my** answer meant. Unlike many literal answers to the questions "how to shoot myself in the leg", my answers indeed helpful.

Comment: @Shrapnel just telling you how you come across to me on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can put image data into a cache and you might be able to gain some speed advantage from it over including them from the filesystem. However, you can and should also utilize browser and proxy caching, which makes more sense to me:

- [Google Web Performance Best Practices - Optimize caching](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html)

and maybe some webservers which utilize memcache:

- http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModMemCache
- http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMemcachedModule
- http://www.mmcache.com/

Since the question was not limited to image caching though and asked for PHP, here is a list of general (opcodes) caches that you can use from PHP

- [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/#Performance)
- [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC)
- [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)
- [eAccelerator](http://www.eaccelerator.net/)
- [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

Comment: I am curious, What of these will serve images?

Answer (score 2):

Zend has a good caching tool if you want to check it out but I'm not sure about the image cache.

You could also check this link for a related stuff :

- [How to get the browser to cache images, with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385964/how-to-get-the-browser-to-cache-images-with-php)