# How to read a file from browsers cache?

Tags: caching, cookies, gif

I had made a GIF-file with more (hidden) information in it self, then only the picture-data.
Like so:

```
<?php
// set variabelen
    $naam = "gebruikersinformatie"; 
    $info['age'] = 27;
    $info['number'] = '1234.56.789';
    $info['name'] = 'Arie Noniem';
    $info['unique_hash'] = base64_encode(implode("|", array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'],$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])));

    // build the information
    $info = base64_encode(http_build_query($info));

    // build the image
    header('Content-type: image/gif');  
    echo base64_decode("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7\n".$info);
?>-
```

Now, i would like to check if the file is already in user's cache.
If not: make a new one (with code above).
If is in cache: read that gif.gif file with PHP, as there is more information stored in it.

Question: how to check if the file is in the cache? [How to get the browser to cache images, with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385964/how-to-get-the-browser-to-cache-images-with-php) doesnt work correctly

And how to read the cached file? So PHP gets the real contents from the cached file?
Reason: to avoid EU-cookie-law

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't be avoiding EU Cookie Law.

Although it's commonly become known as cookie law it is a privacy directive with principles applying to any technology where information is placed, held or read from the user's device. So necessity for compliance includes for instance Flash files (Locally Stored Objects), tracking pixels (invisible one pixel images typically used for tracking email opens) and other stuff too.

Just for reference, this answer is based in our experience in putting together [ukcookieslaw.co.uk](http://ukcookieslaw.co.uk) to deal specifically with the UK implementation of the EU Directive (noticing the German in your coding :-).

Assuming at the least privacy invasive your solution was doing the same as a session cookie and providing a necessary function (like maintaining a log-in) one could argue your solution is actually less compliant, as a session cookie will be (usually) destroyed at latest when the user quits the browser.

Your more obscured, difficult to inspect, deliberately hidden (I appreciate there's no malicious intent) payload can, and given that most people do not empty their cache each time they quit, will hang around for longer. In fact, in a way you're relying on that.

Without the details one can't take a view, but it may be that the information is more available to third parties, i.e. is there a possibility of caching of the image by intermediaries in the network that you would have to protect against?

You would still have to describe your use of personal data, and rely on either implied consent (or explicit consent) for placing data on the user's device for your site's compliance. Problem is that any consent must be INFORMED consent, and it would appear on the face of it that informing the user is furthest from your mind.

I think you need a better reason for your engineering effort :-)

kind regards,

Philip

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I know why i will use this method.
For now, its just a typical 1x1 pixel, but i should integrate it in a needed image.
Therefore: can i read a cached image with PHP? If yes: how?