# How to detect if the browser requests a certain file from the server

Tags: php, webserver

Can I detect if the web browser is requesting a certain image from the server? 
I want to check if the user downloads the image or if it is already cached from its browser.

### The main idea:

I am counting unique visitors per profile page. I use `IPs` and `Cookies` for now but want to add this, too. `IP` could be changed easily, `Cookie` could be blocked/deleted. 
My idea is to use this information just like a `flash cookie`. The image will be `1px x 1px` in size and will be invisible to the user. I don't have experience with ActionScript and Flash at all, so I can't use `flash cookie` and want to try with this.

**EDIT:** 
As I understand from Sven's answer maybe I couldn't explain what I need. My question is same as Sven's answer. **How to** `wait for the request to appear on the server`? I want the browser to cache the image, so it will be downloaded only if the user is an unique visitor, i.e. he is viewing the page for the very first time.

I want to get this information and check if the image is requested or not (i.e. it is cached). Something like:

```
$requested_files = $_SERVER['REQUESTS']; // Or something similar, this is the question.
$file_name = $profile_page_owner_id.'.png'; // For example.

if(in_array($file_name, $requested_files)) {
    // File is requested, so it is not cached. This is an unique visitor.
    // Of course except this I will continue to check IP and Cookie.
    // This will be the 3rd check.
} else {
    // File is not requested, so it is already cached.
    // Page is viewed before, this is not an unique visitor.
}
```

Comment: Is it a bad idea. People could not have flash, block flash by default, or delete their flash cookies, so you wouldn't be more secure. IP's + user agent of the browser is one of the safest ways you can count this. Think about this, is it really VITAL that if a user change their IP (which, FYI, isn't easy), then it counts as one more unique visit?

Comment: Flash cookies could be deleted, of course. But this is made very rarely compared to HTTP cookies. And as I said I can't use flash cookies because I don't have enough knowledge about Flash and ActionScript at all. Googled for some `PHP Flash cookie tutorials` but couldn't find something helpful. Unique visits are vital because we want to pay bonuses to our users with most unique visits for their profile pages, so this is not only an informative statistic. Finally, could you provide me some example for IP+User Agent because I couldn't find how to use User Agent effectively on this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Have your image path set to, let's say `user_track.php`, the browser will request the file, where you do your logging, then send the appropriate headers and the image itself.

You can even send cache-denial headers, so that the image won't be cached by default.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean. Can you give me some example, please? Also I don't want to deny caching. If the image is cached, I will interpret this like "He viewed this page before, so it is not an unique view".

Answer (score 1):

Just create a PHP file that will output an image, add the logics you need (counting and stuff) before the output, call the php file in an html image and force the image to be cached by sending a header like `header('Cache-Control: max-age=37739520, public');`

You can take a look at this post: [How to get the browser to cache images, with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385964/how-to-get-the-browser-to-cache-images-with-php) for more information about caching.

Comment: Ok, e.g. I am using `<img src="showImage.php?id=12345">` and in the php file I am getting the ID and echo the filename: `12345.png`. But how would I detect if this image was cached or it is requested for the very first time from the client's browser?

Comment: If you send the right headers - the browser will request the image only once - so every request is an unique one. You can check this logics using the Developers Tools in Google Chrome (F12 -> Network -> refresh your page and see if it's loaded from the cache).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But how to check server side whether the image is downloaded or cached? Should I read the browser cache every time someway? Checking manually from Chrome is OK but I should do the same thing via PHP.

Comment: You can't - you have to rely on the browser's caching ability. There is no way in differing a new user who downloads the item for the first time and an old user, who has his cache expired (or deleted). Try combining this method with IP and/or cookie support to achieve the best effect.

Comment: I am using IP & Cookies already. This will be my 3rd auxiliary step. Each visit will be for 24 hours. So same user will be a unique visitor again after 1 day (24h). Cache expiration time is not very important. I don't think it will be less than 24 hours in most cases. And if the cache is deleted, eh, cookies could be deleted, too, IP could be changed... I know that I can't track unique visitors with 100% success when there is not an authorization.

Comment: You can't rely on the user / browser to delete his cache. You have to send correct cache expiration time in the header of your php image.

Comment: Ok, I will set it to 24 hours. But it is not the main problem. When user opens the page, how to check if the image is cached or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect it by simply waiting for the request to appear on the server.

If you get a request, the browser has not cached it.

If you do not want the browser to cache it, simply say so in the http headers. Then you'll get the request every time.

Edit: Ok, if you WANT caching of the image, simply send cache headers that allow for indefinite caching in the browser. Usually the image will then be requested only once. The detection of the request stays the same.

Comment: I edited my question, you can see it again. This is exactly what I need. How to do that?