# How to setup static assets caching with apache?

Tags: apache, caching, fingerprinting

I'd like to optimize caching of static assets (.js, .css, ... files) used in our web. My goal is based on this article (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses).

In short - because these static assets tend to be updated ad-hoc (sometimes weekly, sometimes twice a day, ...) I'd like to cache them with far future expiration and give them unique names based on the content or modification date or similar. This should allow to have them cached for a long time but have them updated as soon as some change occurs.

Is this technique supported by Apache2 server? Or is there some middle ware system which handles fingerprints generating (to have unique asset names) and updating references to them in HTML file (which won't be cached at all)?

We use LAMP stack on our host.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @AlisterBulman & `@sitilge
Thank you both, gonna read all the articles you recommended.

Got also advice from the other lad to use [PageSpeed Module for Apache](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration). Do you know if that might be a good solution?

Comment: choose the answer that helped (and is considered to solve the problem) and reward the respective author :) about the pagespeed module - if you minify, cache, optimize the code on your own then using the module will be an overhead. Otherwise, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of techniques, some better than others. One good one is to have the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This allows URLs of the form `/i/filename.1433499948.gif` - but the file that is actually read from disk is just `/i/filename.gif` parts 1 and 3 of the filename.

This Apache vhost/.htaccess stanza is from [H5BP filename-based_cache_busting.conf](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/h5bp/web_performance/filename-based_cache_busting.conf) file, and there are other examples of good practices in the repository.

That, combined with the H5BP [mod_expires](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/h5bp/web_performance/cache_expiration.conf) config, mean you will always be able to trivially renew the users local browser cache with just updating the reference to the file by a new name.

Comment: Hello @AlisterBulman How to solve this same issue for youtube image and css file?

Answer (score 5):

You can enable `mod_mime`, `mod_expires` for Apache and use the following snippet

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jp?g|gif|ico|mp4|wmv|mov|mpeg|css|map|woff?|eot|svg|ttf|js|json|pdf|csv)">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 weeks"
</FilesMatch>
```

Or set the respective `php` headers

```
session_cache_limiter('none');
header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*7)); //one week
header('Expires: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,time()+60*60*24*365)); //one week
```

Also related article here: [How to get the browser to cache images, with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385964/how-to-get-the-browser-to-cache-images-with-php)