# Phalcon, HTTP Cache of a generated image

Tags: php, apache, http, caching, phalcon

I'm writing a web service who generate thumbs of images with Phalcon.

I try to HTTP cache it.

This is my code :

```
$seconds = 43200;
$expireDate = new DateTime();
$expireDate->modify("+ $seconds seconds");

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$app->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'Content-type: ' . $finfo->buffer($data));

$app->response->setExpires($expireDate);
$app->response->setHeader('Pragma', 'cache');
$app->response->setHeader('Cache-Control', "private, max-age=$seconds");
$app->response->setHeader('E-Tag', md5(filemtime($path)));
$app->response->setHeader('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)).' GMT');

$app->response->sendHeaders();
echo $data;
```

The image is corretly displayed. But when you refresh it, the http code is always 200, I try on another image of another website and I've got 200, 304, 304, 304...

This is my raw response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 18:38:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Expires: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 06:38:41 GMT
Pragma: cache
Cache-Control: private, max-age=43200
E-Tag: 501a8d62f276eb5b165b8a709bf4e5b4
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Jul 2015 20:34:14 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=90
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Someone see what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/1385982/576893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code needs to return the 304 Not Modified header when the browser asks if the cached image is still valid. Put an if statement at the top of your script to handle that request before sending the image again.

You are always sending the image that's why the browser is showing a 200 response.

Comment: Thanks for all !

This is my solution :

$filemtimeOk = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && $filemtime <= strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
    $etagOk = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] == $etag;

    if ($filemtimeOk && $etagOk) {
        $app->response->setStatusCode(304, "Not Modified");
        $app->response->sendHeaders();
    } else {
         // Normal case ...
    }
}

Comment: Unless you're serving up exceptionally large content, or extending the cache time, a 304 response will worsen rendering performance and won't reduce load on the server by much.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the max-age to the last-modified date you get an expiry time in the past.

Your code is a mess of every possible way to influence caching (and btw http does not define a "pragma: cache" header). As to the question of what you *should* be doing, that depends on what you are trying to acheive - just getting load off the server, faster page rendering or caching up to apre-planned replacement or something else. And you haven't told us what this is.

Comment: I just follow this tutorial :
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/response.html#http-cache

Yes of course, with the cache I try too load off the server and speed up the client rendering, it's the cache definition no ?

Btw, pregma cache header exists in HTTP, but only in HTTP/1.0 implementation. Thanks. But same result without.

Comment: The tutorial does not say "use all these". And "Pragma: cache" is not in HTTP 1.0 either. Have a look at https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/ (introductory) or http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP-Performance-ebook/dp/B00U7E00H2 (advanced)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks PaulS !

```
$filemtimeOk = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && $filemtime <= strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
$etagOk = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] == $etag;

if ($filemtimeOk && $etagOk) {
    $app->response->setStatusCode(304, "Not Modified");
    $app->response->sendHeaders();
} else {
    // Normal case... (send data and headers)
}
```