# Why doesn't edge cache images

Tags: php, caching, microsoft-edge, browser-cache

I noticed that for my page in Chrome and Firefox all the images are stored in cache after I load the page. But on Edge it doesn't is there anyway to force edge to cache the images? By setting cache-control headers?

Network debug and headers on Chrome
[image: Network debug on Chrome]
[image]

Network debug and header on Firefox (**gebufferd means cached**)
[image: Network debug on Firefox]
[image]

Network debug and header on Edge (Only css files are cached)
[image: Network debug on Edge]
[image]

Comment: removed the javascript tag. This has nothing to do with javascript. @nico Maybe you can post the headers too that the webserver sends.

Comment: @ErwinMoller I think i have added what you wanted me to add? :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting a future `Cache-control: max-age` and `Expires` header? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385982/296555

Comment: Please check the [request header Cache-control property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK5aI.png), you are setting the max-age as '0', so, it will not cache the images. Try to modify it. More detail information about cache-control, please check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

Comment: I have added the following headers


`session_cache_limiter('none');`
`header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));`
`header('Expires: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,time()+60*60*24*365));`


Doesn't fix it, Edge still has the same request header and doesnt load images from cache

Comment: Try to use Microsoft Edge browser to access the [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/), then using F5 to refresh page to check whether the image is loaded from cache and the response date/expires value? You could refer to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIclC.png). If the image still not from the cache, perhaps the issue is related to the Edge browser setting, try to reset the Edge Browser setting. If the image in this page load from cache, perhaps the issue is related to your website server side, please check the server side setting(the image expires date).